# Upgrading Facebook Graph API Version

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I would like to upgrade my Facebook application Graph API version from v2.3 to v2.9 .
I researched my application's usage of the Graph and Marketing APIs, and saw that it is calling the Marketing API with the version explicitly in the url.
Regarding the Graph API, the only config for it's version is in the app Dashboard (in the FB developer dashboard).

If I change the version in the Dashboard - will it affect only the non-explicit calls for the Graph API? or also the explicit calls to the marketing api?

Comment: You can not change the API version in dashboard. It works the same way in Graph API as with the Marketing API - API version is specified directly in the URL.

Comment: Is it possible to make my calls without specifying the API version? Thanks! @CBroe

Comment: Yes, but then it will automatically fall back to the lowest API version your app can use that it still available.